# How to understand やすくて in this sentence?

Tags: translation, meaning

How to understand やすくて in this sentence:

> 制服を買ってみたのは　はじめてですが
> 見やすくてとても助かっています！
>
> At first time I tried to buy an uniform, but...

安くて is て-form of 安い, right?

I can guess that in English it may be:

> At first time I tried to buy an uniform, but it looks cheap...

or something like this.

Comment: 'to look cheap' would be 安っぽく見える by the way.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not 安い; it is 易い.  [Verb stem] + やすい means "easy to 〜".

So it is a uniform that is "easy to see" (or possibly figuratively "looks good").

Comment: +1: Who downvoted? It is a correct answer!

Comment: I guess it meant how the uniform or other goods were displayed (possibly in the web page).

Comment: I'm confused too as to what 見やすい is referring to; wwwjdic lists the 'attractive' sense as archaic, so it seems unlikely that sense would be the one in question. ([Also cross-checked 大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/213663/meaning/m1u/%E8%A6%8B%E6%98%93%E3%81%84/); the sample for sense 3 there is very old.)

Comment: Can somebody help to explain what 見易くてとても助かっています means? "looks good, very helpful?". I'm quite confuse, Thanks.

Comment: @Alice28 Good point.  I see two problems with this answer.  (1) Very few people, like almost no one, would say 見やすい to refer to "good-looking" clothes in the first place.  (2) If someone did use it to mean that, it still would not explain the 助かっています part that follows.  That would be a highly unnatural collocation and logic.   When I read the question, I thought the exact same thing as user4092 mentioned above.

Comment: @Alice28 If the guess of user4092 is right, it is translated as "I appreciate the easily viewable display。

Comment: @Yuuichi Tam i see, so 助かっています literally means 'the easy viewable display is helping me'. That's make sense. So the complete meaning of the sentence could be 'It's my firstime trying to bought uniform here. The displays are easy and helpful' (so the sentence shows that she had a pleasant experience there).

Comment: @Alice28 助かる means one is saved and 助かっている means one is in the state of being saved. The te form as in 見やすくて stands for reason or cause here. The whole sentence goes "because it's easy to see, I am saved".